# Extension function can't be imported from library

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

After updating android gradle plugin version from `3.5.0` to `4.1.0-alpha06`, extension function defined in one of my android library project can't be imported in consuming projects. (Normal classes can be used without any issue)

I've compared both the `jar`s (one built-with `3.5.0` and another built-with `4.1.0-alpha06`) and found out that the `META-INF` directory missing in new jar.

**Working Jar - Built-with 3.5.0**

[image]

**Not Working Jar - Built-with 4.1.0-alpha06**

[image]

How to fix this issue ?

Comment: I'm having same issue. What I noticed is that META-INF is generated for kotlin only modules, but if it's an android library module then they are missing. For now I'm building my libraries with 4.1.0-alpha03

Comment: Yeah, I did the same as a workaround

Comment: Seems like alpha10 solves this issue

Answer (score 5):

You need to keep kotlin_module in apk/META-INF

So check your build.gradle and remove this line

```
packagingOptions {
   exclude("META-INF/*.kotlin_module") 
}
```